# converting error from vb.net to c#

Tags: c#

```
VB.NEt Code
Dim rRow As DataRow
For intI = 0 To lstColumns.Count - 1
    If lstColumns.Item(intI).tablename = strCurrentTable Then
        rRow(lstColumns.Item(intI).ColumnName) = lstColumns.Item(intI).ColumnData
    End If
Next intI

////when convert from vb.net to c#code error
for (intI = 0; intI <= lstColumns.Count - 1; intI++) //lstcolumn is arraylist
{  
    if (lstColumns[intI].ToString() == strCurrentTable) // lstacoulumn is arraylist
    {   
        rRow[lstColumns[intI]]= lstColumns[intI].ToString(); // Error on this line
    }
```

==> Error are following
cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Data.DataColumn'

Comment: And what is the error...?  what is `rRow`?

Comment: look like a boss? My boss speaks equal. :D

Comment: Without being able to run your code and see what the error is ourselves, we are at the mercy of you **telling** us what the error is. Without that crucial bit of information anything we would come up with would be a Guess

Comment: put // before the last line - no more error!

Comment: What was the original VB.net code, also as it was asked earlier what is rRow ? I am suspecting it is a DataRow but....

Comment: It looks like you are you are changing the underling controls of this method, what was lstColumns before you changed it to an ArrayList?

Comment: lstcolumn are arraylist

Answer (score 0):

This is actual C# after convertion

```
DataRow rRow = default(DataRow);
for (intI = 0; intI <= lstColumns.Count - 1; intI++)
{
    if (lstColumns.Item(intI).tablename == strCurrentTable) 
        {
        rRow(lstColumns.Item(intI).ColumnName) = lstColumns.Item(intI).ColumnData;
    }
}
```